# "Error: npm.load() required" while updating npm

Tags: npm

I wanted to install IO Broker on my RaspberryPi 4. I think it was already installed, so I entered few updating commends and now I'm getting all the time this error message:
Error: npm.load() required"

```
pi@raspberrypi:\~ $ sudo npm install -g npm@latest
TypeError: isexe is not a function
at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:7)
at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:91:7)
at which (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:92:5)
at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:250:5)
at EventEmitter.npm.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:246:5)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79:7
at Object.\<anonymous\> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:155:3)
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59
throw new Error('npm.load() required')
Error: npm.load() required
at Object.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13)
at process.errorHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:208:32)
at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
at process.\_fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:167:25)
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: try to update node.js and npm

Comment: it's not working, I'm getting all the time same error:

"pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm list -g
TypeError: isexe is not a function
(...)
      ^
Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:208:32)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:167:25)"

Comment: problem solved, I have reinstalled the whole OS, an update was not possible